# Where can I find the META-INF file for 1.6.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've checked everywhere but I can't find the meta-inf folder so that i can delete it to get mods working. I've checked in the 1.6.4 version folder but there was nothing in the except two folders called 1.6.4 and 1.6.4.json.

Answer (score 3):

META-INF folder can be found from inside the `1.6.4.jar` under `versions/1.6.4`, or if your system is hiding the extension, the file will be called `1.6.4`. You need to open the file with a program such as WinRAR or 7-zip.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I didn't know the location had changed but my answer is correct for the old launcher